What's this big pole the camera attached to (typically found on studio)
On big studios, instead of tripod, you'll see the photographers put their cameras on this big pole.


Rising/sliding the camera on such thing is indeed much more convenient. What's the name of that thing?

or studio camera stand, and they in turn slot into a base, some static, some with lockable castors. Basically sturdy and takes up a lot less space than a traditional tripod.

Column Stand; also sometimes called Studio Stand or Camera Stand. Combine the terms for the best search results... ("Studio Column Stand").

Ah I see.... someone told me to check this: https://www.foba.com/en/products/category/studio-stands/

This device is called a dolly.
A professional studio has lots of equipment because everyday the tasks will be different. Some days, still photography, some days cine, some days
copy work etc.
The dolly is on wheels, easy to move and position even if the camera lash-ups are heavy.
This is just one of the tools of a well-equipped studio.
